# Errno 2 File b' does not exist: in heroku django

Tags: django, heroku

this is my heroku logs
i am unable to find the error

```
2019-04-13T22:10:54.235790+00:00 app[web.1]: File 
"pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", li
ne 387, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
2019-04-13T22:10:54.235792+00:00 app[web.1]: File 
"pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", li
ne 705, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
2019-04-13T22:10:54.235794+00:00 app[web.1]: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] 
File b
 'D:\\FINAL PRODUCT (4-4-19)\\dunya.csv' does not exist: b'D:\\FINAL 
  PRODUCT 
 (4-4
 -19)\\dunya.csv'
```

i get this log please anyone can help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku cannot find the file using the path that you mentioned in code because you provided an absolute path instead of relative.

You should use relative paths instead of absolute path.

```
"dunya.csv"
```

instead of

```
"D:\\FINAL PRODUCT (4-4-19)\\dunya.csv"
```

Comment: thank you soo much .. this answer is very usefull and easy for me .. i was doing a shitty mistake .. thanks bro